# Find history or events of a deleted app in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Good Evening,
I had an app on cloud foundry which got deleted somehow and I wanted to know the history or events about that application. I couldn't find any cf cli command to do that.
The cf events  doesn't work as it needs an alive app. Doesn't work on deleted apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the events history by calling the CF API

`$ cf curl /v2/events`.

You can get at most 100 events on a page. So you will have to iterate thru it.

If you have the timeframe around which you deleted the app, you can do something like this ..

`cf curl "/v2/events?order-direction=desc&results-per-page=100&page=1&q=timestamp%3E2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"`

Get the app guid and then search events by the app's guid.

Here is the link to the [CF API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/250/) docs.